# Is there an easy way to autowire empty collection if no beans present in Spring?

Tags: java, spring

If I have `@Autowired List<SomeBeanClass> beans;` and no beans of `SomeBeanClass`, I get:

> No matching bean of type [SomeBeanClass] found for dependency [collection of SomeBeanClass]: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

If I add `(required=false)`, I get `null` for `beans`. But it looks like error prone solution requiring null checks.

***Is there an easy way (one liner) to autowire empty collection if no beans present?***

Answer (score 25, accepted):

> If I add `(required=false)`, I get `null` for `beans`.

Does the field get explicitly set to null or does it simply not get set at all?  Try adding an initializer expression

```java
@Autowired(required=false) List<SomeBeanClass> beans = new ArrayList<>();
```

Comment: This won't work. Spring will still complain it can't do its thing.

Comment: Unless you put `required = false`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis that was the case I was referring to, sorry, I didn't make it very clear.

Comment: It is better to assign `Collections.EMPTY_LIST` (or `ImmutableList.<SomeBeanClass>of()` if you use Guava).

Comment: How can I do this with constructor injection?

Comment: @Chomeh I'd mark it as `required=false` and then do the null check myself in the constructor. There may be a way to automate it but I don't know of one myself - ask a separate SO question and see if anyone else has suggestions.

Comment: @Autowired(required=false) List<SomeBeanClass> beans = Collections.emptyList();

Answer (score 49):

There are a few options with Spring 4 and Java 8:

```
@Autowired(required=false)
private List<Foo> providers = new ArrayList<>();
```

You can also use `java.util.Optional` with a constructor:

```
@Autowired
public MyClass(Optional<List<Foo>> opFoo) {
    this.foo = opFoo.orElseGet(ArrayList::new);
}
```

You should also be able to autowire an a field with `Optional<List<Foo>> opFoo;`, but I haven't used that yet.

Comment: Thanks! 
If the list of beans is immutable, it is better to use Collections.emptyList() instead of new ArrayList<>().